# No internet after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet, 17.10

I just upgraded my dual-boot Laptop (Asus P53E) to (K)ubuntu 17.10
and now no internet connection is working. It looks perfect, like "connected to WiFi ....", "connected to ethernet ..." in the network manager, but in fact
no data is transmitted. The built-in devices are Ethernet Qualcomm AR8151 and 
WLAN Qualcomm 9285. I already tried some standard hints on the web, but they do not show any effect. By the way, on the windows 7 side, the devices work properly, so it is a linux issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: problems solved by first answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same problem. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, I removed the line `dns=dnsmasq`, then my internet was working fine. I am not an advanced user, so am not sure this will work for you, but just wanted to share my experience.

To do so, open terminal then enter the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

then add `#` before `dns=dnsmasq` and save the file.

Comment: It really solved my problem! It is highly appreciated and helped a lot!