# Ubuntu 17.10 : internet does not work and I can´t fix it

Tags: wireless, 17.10, internet, ethernet

I updated my Ubuntu OS to 17.10 a few days ago. Internet connection has worked fine during the installation but broke after that (nor ethernet, nor wifi)
I know this is a known problem for 17.10.
I tried all the solutions I met on forums, such as :
- restart service NetworkManager ,
- edit NetworkManager.conf [ adding the lines : [device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no]
- edit my wifi driver conf 
- this one too : [No internet after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966743/no-internet-after-upgrading-from-17-04-to-17-10)
(but there is not such a line to comment in my .conf)

Still nothing and, well, I really don't know how to fix it... and I really need an operational internet on my Ubuntu.

Note : I have a dual boot with windows 7, everything works fine on W7 (same hardware). Seems this is an Ubuntu problem.

Any idea ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3`

Comment: Thanks, and sorry to not have you answered sooner. Finally, I've updated to Ubuntu 18.04 (Beta Release). Till now, it works properly ! But at the beginning, Ubuntu 17.10 worked well too...